# Why I'm getting two different outputs?

Tags: python, json, rest, python-requests, postman

I'm trying to access IBM Maximo by REST.
I was able to do it with Postman by doing a GET request to check if the a particular incident exists:
[Postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu5DR.png).
Now I want to do it in Python but I can't have the same output:

```
params = {
    'oslc.select':'*', 
    'oslc.where':'ticketid="IN43550232"',
    }

r = requests.get(url,params=params)
```

When I **print(r.text)** the output is the html of a page and when I **print(r.json())** I get:

> File "C:\Users\User.spyder-py3\Projects\GET.py", line
> 27, in 
> print(r.json())
>
> File
> "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py",
> line 897, in json
> return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\json_*init*_.py",
> line 348, in loads
> return _default_decoder.decode(s)
>
> File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line
> 337, in decode
> obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
>
> File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line
> 355, in raw_decode
> raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
>
> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

From what I understant the output is not in a json format... My question is, how can I solve this problem? Thank you

SOLUTION:

```
headers = {
    'Cookie':'...',
    'Accept':'*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    }
params = {
    'oslc.select':'*', 
    'oslc.where':'ticketid="IN43550232"',
    }

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
r.encoding = 'utf-8'
print(r.json())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the quotes. Like this:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params, verify=False)
```

Comment: My mistake, in my code there's no quotes. Thank you very much

Comment: Other than that, what about the headers? are you defining them before you call requests.get?

Comment: It can also be that the response is simply not in JSON format, and therefore the JSON decoder throws an exception https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content

Comment: I think it's that... But why would it be in JSON format in Postman and not in JSON format using Python requests.get?

Comment: My guess is that Postman is parsing the raw response behind the scenes

Comment: I think the problem is that when: print(r.enconding) the output is None

Comment: The solution is the set r.encoding='utf-8'